# Customized loss function for Random Forest for Regression in R

Tags: r, random-forest, loss-function, mlr3, r-ranger

I want to implement my own customized loss function for a random forest regression in R. I found this [Random Forests with a Customized Loss Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078332/random-forests-with-a-customized-loss-function) on how to do it in python, however not in R.

I would think that maybe the mlr3 package lets you customize loss functions in any way? I only found how to customize performance measures for assessing performance, and not for training. Any help or hints are appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if package `randomForest` admits custom objective function (i guess no, because regression method is automatically established from the response data type). Xgboost [can be set to work as randomForest](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/rf.html) and admits custom objective functions. An also has the benefit of speed.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer @RicVillalba, that looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mlr3` doesn't provide any of the actual learners, so you can only do this if the random forest implementation allows to do it. At least the common implementations in R don't allow this.

Of course you can always modify the source code, as suggested in the linked question for Python.